# Correct way to access a member/property of ViewController from Objective-C Class File?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I was just curious about the correct way to go about accessing a property that I have declared in a ViewController and using it in an Objective-C Class file? I have included the .h file, but that doesn't seem to be enough. I know that I could just move it to the app delegate and access it in both places then, but there has to be a cleaner and more direct way.

Edit for clarity:

```
nrViewController.h:

@interface nrViewController : UIViewController {

    NSMutableArray *checkpoints;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *checkpoints;

nrViewController.m

@implementation nrViewController
@synthesize checkpoints;

//A bunch of code, some of which actually uses checkpoints

@end

XMLParser.m:

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Checkpoints"]) {

        checkpoints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    }
```

This isn't totally complete as I would like to us it in more places, but the only other place outside of XMLParser.m would be in nrViewController.m and that I understand how to do that. I would like to declare and use the checkpoints variable in nrViewController, and use it in XMLParser.m as well as I would be loading parse data into it and then manipulating it. I hope this clarifies things a bit more, but if more info is need I would be happy to explain in even more detail.

Thanks!

-Karoly

Comment: Could you edit your question and show us *how* you actually declared it?

Comment: Are you actually calling the property methods on a view controller object?

Comment: @Cyrille: Sorry about that, went ahead and edited to try and clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, hard to follow the idea of question.

If you declared a property and synthesized or coded getters/setters, then it should be available from the other classes as long as you're trying to get it from **object** of the class, where you declared the property.

If you want to use property as a static variable, touching just a class, not an object, then you can do that, but you should either define this variable as static global variable and work with it directly, or you should implement your custom **static** getter/setter methods for that property.
Hope I didn't get confused in some place.

**EDIT**
Observations according to the provided code:
You didn't declare a property, man. For your variable you should use

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *checkpoints;
```

(this is under the closing figure bracket in @interface. And in .m file you should do `@synthesize checkpoints;`

(after the *@implementation nrViewController {* )

Also, access your variable in the way

```
yourNRViewControllerInstance.checkpoints = ...
```

Comment: I figured it might be something like myNRViewControllerINstance.checkpoints, but whenever I try to use it in my XMLParser.m file it defaults to the class NRViewController and doesn't recognize the actual instance, which is why I asked this question. As for needing the synthesis and property declaration that was just lazy editing on my part... sorry >.<

Comment: NP. You should do #import nrViewController.h in your XMLParser.m class also. And of course, myNRViewControllerINstance must be not just allocated in XMLParser: it should be the same object, which you're going to work with then.

Comment: I do import it there, and it still doesn't recognize the specific instance. I tried to do the follow:         appDelegate.RLTableViewController.NRViewController.checkpoints and this seems to be recognized although my specific instances are called myRLTableViewController and myNRViewController so I dont think its the same object. Am I correct in this assumption, or is this how its supposed to look?

Comment: As far as I see, you allocated object RLTableViewController in appDelegate, in you 'RLTableViewController' you allocated NRViewController. In your XMLParser you must work with the same object. That is, either you pass the pointer to *appDelegate.RLTableViewController.NRViewController* in XMLParser when creating object of XMLParser, or you turn to appDelegate and take ref out of there (as you succeeded). But generally speeking seems the architecture of your app is not the best.

Comment: I might end up passing it in on initialize of the parser if it doesn't work through the app delegate. Yea it might seem a little weird but if you saw the whole thing it would make sense :P